Doctrine 3 and database migrations: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'doctrine_migration_versions' already exists
I'm upgrading the Doctrine ORM (part of a Symfony 6 project) to version 3, but there is an issue together with the doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle (v3.3.1).
When I try to run php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction I get the error Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'doctrine_migration_versions' already exists..
Setting the schema_filter in the Doctrine config yaml to '~^(?!doctrine)~' did not solved the issue.
How can I solve that issue?

The regex in your schema_filter did'nt match the table name. Try with `~^(doctrine_migration_versions)~.
